# Equivalence between twists of a curve and torsors of its automorphism group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology, torsors

Let $X$ be a curve defined over a number field $K$, and let $G_K$ be the absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $\text{Aut}(X)$ be the group of $\overline{K}$-defined automorphisms of $X$, and consider the Galois cohomology set $H^1(G_K, \text{Aut}(X))$.

Denote by $\text{Twist}(X/K)$ the set of twists of $X$ up to $K$-defined automorphisms.

According to Silverman, Chapter X.2, Theorem 2.2, there is a bijection
$$\text{Twist}(X/K)\longrightarrow H^1(G_K, \text{Aut}(X)).$$

It is well known that there is an equivalence between a Galois cohomology set, such as $H^1(G_K, \text{Aut}(X))$ and the set of $\text{Aut}(X)$-torsors under $G_K$.

1. Consider $X$ as the trivial twist of itself. In what way is $X$ an $\text{Aut}(X)$ torsor? I mean, in order for $X$ to be an $\text{Aut}(X)$-torsor, we should have a well defined, bijective, action map $X\times \text{Aut}(X)\longrightarrow X$, yet $\text{Aut}(X)$ doesn't even act on $X$, but rather on $\overline{X}:=X\otimes \overline{K}$.
2. Is there a version of the bijection between twists and cohomology classes which holds in higher dimensions as well? A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has actually already been asked here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159071/forms-of-algebraic-varieties

Comment: An excellent reference is given there, namely Section III.1 of Serre's book on Galois cohomology.

Comment: @DanielLoughran ah, you're right! But that only addresses the second question, and my answer focuses also on the first question (interpreted more broadly as 'where is the torsor?').

Comment: I think that an important thing is to notice that the claim is not that twists *are* torsors, but rather that twists are *parameterised* by torsors.  There is a preferred twist of $X$, namely $X$ itself.  And there is a preferred cohomology class of $G_K$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$, and a preferred torsor for $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ (namely, $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$).  And they match!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this has little to do with varieties and is just some general phenomenon in topos theory. For simplicity, let $\mathscr C$ be a (small) category with finite limits, endowed with a Grothendieck pretopology. For a sheaf of groups $\mathscr G$ on $\mathscr C$, write $H^1(\mathscr C,\mathscr G)$ for the set of isomorphism classes of $\mathscr G$-torsors (this has an easy interpretation in terms of cocycles, but I will work only with the torsor point of view). For a sheaf of sets $\mathscr F$ on $\mathscr C$, write $\operatorname{Twist}(\mathscr F)$ for the set of isomorphism classes of twists of $\mathscr F$, i.e. sheaves $\mathscr G$ on $\mathscr C$ for which there exists a covering $\{U_i \to *\}_{i \in I}$ of the terminal object $*$ of $\mathscr C$ such that $\mathscr G|_{U_i} \cong \mathscr F|_{U_i}$ for all $i \in I$.

Define a map $\operatorname{Twist}(\mathscr F) \to H^1(\mathscr C,\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F))$ by taking a twist $\mathscr G$ of $\mathscr F$ to the sheaf $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$, which is naturally an $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)$-torsor by the map
\begin{align*}
\mu \colon \mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) &\to \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)\\
(f,g) &\mapsto f \circ g.
\end{align*}
Indeed, this map is clearly a left action of the sheaf of groups $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)$ on the sheaf of sets $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$, and the map
\begin{align*}
(\mu,\text{pr}_2) \colon \mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) &\to \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) \times \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)\label{1}\tag{1}\\
(f,g) & \mapsto (fg,g)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism (over opens $U$ where $\mathscr G|_U \ncong \mathscr F|_U$, there is nothing to check!).

**Lemma.** *The map $\operatorname{Twist}(\mathscr F) \to H^1(\mathscr C,\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F))$ is a bijection.*

*Proof.* Injectivity is a little more conceptual than what Silverman shows: let $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr H$ be twists of $\mathscr F$ such that $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$ and $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr H,\mathscr F)$ are isomorphic as $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)$-torsors. This means that there exists an isomorphism $\alpha \colon \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr Isom(\mathscr H,\mathscr F)$ such that the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) & \to & \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr Isom(\mathscr H,\mathscr F) & \to & \mathscr Isom(\mathscr H,\mathscr F)\end{array}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
commutes, where the horizontal maps are the actions and the vertical maps are given by $\alpha$. In particular, we get a map
$$\psi \colon \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr H)$$
taking a local section $f \colon \mathscr G|_U \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr F|_U$ to the composition $\mathscr G|_U \stackrel f\to \mathscr F|_U \stackrel{\alpha(f)^{-1}}\longrightarrow \mathscr H|_U$. We will show that $\psi$ descends to a map $* \to \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr H)$, i.e. induces an isomorphism of sheaves $\mathscr G \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr H$.

For ease of notation, write $\mathscr T$ for the $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)$-torsor $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$. Then the map $\psi$ gives two maps $\psi_1, \psi_2 \colon \mathscr T \times \mathscr T \rightrightarrows \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr H)$ by $\psi_i = \psi \circ \text{pr}_i$, and it suffices to show that these agree (since $\mathscr T \times \mathscr T \rightrightarrows \mathscr T \to *$ is a coequaliser). But \eqref{1} gives an isomorphism $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr T \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr T \times \mathscr T$, and the compositions $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F) \times \mathscr T \rightrightarrows \mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr H)$ are given by $(f,g) \mapsto \alpha(fg)^{-1}fg$ and $(f,g) \mapsto \alpha(g)^{-1}g$ respectively. By \eqref{2}, the first map takes $(f,g)$ to $(f\alpha(g))^{-1}fg = \alpha(g)^{-1}g$, which is what we needed to show.

Surjectivity, as in Silverman, relies on descent theory (glueing). Let $\mathscr U = \{U_i \to *\}_{i \in I}$ be a covering over which $\mathscr T$ has sections $g_i$ for all $i \in I$, and define a glueing datum for a sheaf of sets $\mathscr G$ as follows: over $U_i$ take the sheaf $\mathscr G_i = \mathscr F|_{U_i}$, and for each $i,j \in I$ take the isomorphism $\phi_{ij} \colon \mathscr G_j|_{U_i \cap U_j} \stackrel\sim\to \mathscr G_i|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ as the unique section $\phi_{ij}$ of $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)(U_i \cap U_j)$ such that $\phi_{ij} g_j = g_i$. This satisfies the cocycle condition, turning $(\{\mathscr G_i\},\{\phi_{ij}\})$ into a glueing datum. Then there exists a sheaf $\mathscr G$ on $\mathscr C$ such that $\mathscr G|_{U_i} = \mathscr G_i$ for all $i \in I$; see [Stacks, Tag [04TR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TR)]. It is easy to check that the $\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)$-torsor $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathscr T$. $\square$

Here is an even more high-brow argument using stacks of groupoids (= 'sheaves of 1-truncated homotopy types). Let $B(\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F))$ be the stackification of the prestack $U \mapsto B(\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F|_U))$, and let $\mathbf{Twist}$ be the stack taking $U \in \mathscr C$ to the category of twists of $\mathscr F|_U$ (with only invertible morphisms). The thing we're trying to understand is $\operatorname{Twist}(\mathscr F) = \pi_0(\mathbf{Twist}(\mathscr F)(*))$ (the objects up to isomorphism of the category of global sections of the stack $\mathbf{Twist}(\mathscr F)$).

There is a natural map $B(\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F|_U)) \to \mathbf{Twist}(\mathscr F)(U)$ mapping the unique object of $B(\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F|_U))$ to the trivial twist $\mathscr F|_U$ of $\mathscr F|_U$. The construction of stackification [Stacks, Tag [02ZN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02ZN)] shows that the associated morphism of stacks $B(\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)) \to \mathbf{Twist}(\mathscr F)$ is an equivalence, giving a bijection $\operatorname{Twist}(\mathscr F) \stackrel\sim\to \pi_0(B\mathscr Aut(\mathscr F)(*))$. But for any group object $\mathscr G$ in a topos, the category $(B\mathscr G)(*)$ of global sections of $B\mathscr G$ is the category of $\mathscr G$-torsors.

In particular, we've upgraded our bijection of 'objects up to a suitable notion of isomorphism' to an equivalence of groupoids!

---

For the scheme case, there is an extra difficulty that a twist $\mathscr G$ of a representable sheaf $\mathscr F$ (i.e. representable by a scheme $X$) need not be representable (by a scheme $Y$). More or less by definition (of algebraic space), the twist $\mathscr G$ is at least an algebraic space $Y$, as it is an étale sheaf quotient of the scheme $X_{\bar K}$. If $X$ is projective, it has an ample line bundle, which you can use to produce an ample line bundle on $Y$, so $Y$ is projective as well (hence a scheme).

(Proof sketch: an ample line bundle $\mathscr L$ on $X$ gives an ample line bundle on $Y_L$ after some finite Galois extension $K \to L$, and you can apply the norm map $N_{L/K} \colon \mathbf{Pic}_Y(L) \to \mathbf{Pic}_Y(K)$ to get a line bundle on $Y$. It is ample since it is a sum of Galois conjugates of an ample line bundle. Exercise: find some details to worry about.)

Comment: "If $X$ is projective..." Even when $X$ is quasi-projective, the twisted sheaf is representable by a scheme. See Serre, Algebraic groups and class fields, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1988,  Section V.4, Corollary 2 of Proposition 12. (A classical reference...)

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi right, I found that in the other Serre reference too (Galois cohomology, see Daniel Loughran's comments). I was overly cautious in my answer.

Comment: My reference is older: the French edition of 1959,. A yet earlier reference is:
Andre Weil, The Field of Definition of a Variety,
American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 78, No. 3 (Jul., 1956), pp. 509-524 (16 pages)
https://doi.org/10.2307/2372670.  Weil'  paper is *absolutely* unreadable!

Comment: Here I imagine that in the notion of a twist you actually want the isomorphisms to be compatible on the intersections (i.e. satisfy the cocycle condition), so that this isomorphism may be said to come from a global isomorphism, similar to how one defines the twist of a projective curve. Also, is there any reference to the notion/definition of the twist of a sheaf? It is different than what is classically called a twisted sheaf.

Comment: I don't think there's a cocycle condition in twisting, is there? In the definition of a twist of a curve (e.g. Silverman, Ch. X, §2) there is only the *existence* of an isomorphism. Another familiar example is vector bundles: these are twists (or forms) of $\mathcal O_X^r$, but the local isomorphisms do not satisfy a cocycle condition.

Comment: Regarding terminology, you might be right that the use 'twist' (or 'form') for these things is non-standard. I think the topos-theory language uses the bland 'locally isomorphic': we're classifying objects that are locally isomorphic to a given one. (Note that the algebraic geometry literature barely ever mentions sheaves of sets — usually only representable sheaves or sheaves of abelian groups.)

Comment: Very interesting! I was thinking for some reason the underlying category in the case of projective schemes was the small Zariski site of the scheme we take twists thereof, but instead it is "the Galois site" (I think that's what it's called) of some number field.